# i have a my family but my phone has no record of it

Tags: microsoft-account

I have created a family on the computer, but when I go to download apps on my phone it won't let me. It says that I need to go to http://window.com/family to create my family even though I have already. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/set-up-my-family-for-windows-phone)? And have you added the account that you use to sign into your phone as a child account?